# CakePHP Testing Controller AssertLayout / AssertTemplate already return nothing

Tags: php, cakephp

I have this implemented in my PagesControllerTest

```
<?php
namespace App\Test\TestCase\Controller;

use App\Controller\PagesController;
use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestTrait;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;


class PagesControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use IntegrationTestTrait;

    /*public $fixtures = [
        'app.Pages'
    ];*/

    public function setUp(){
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testIndex()
    {
        $this->assertTemplate("default");
    }

}
```

already if I run the phpunit tests I get the error `"Failed asserting that 'default' equals template file ."`
I hope anyone can tell me why the assertTemplate function already returns empty. I think I missed some initialisation but I don't know. The layout in the pagesController is actually disabled but if I comment it out and use default, the result remains same. Nothing.

Comment: Sounds like you fixed your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961674/cakephp-3-phpunit-lower-version-error-in-new-installation problem? If so, please either post an answer, or delete the question - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test doesn't actually issue a request, please re-read the docs closely, you need to use the `get()/post()/etc` methods to simulate a request, quote:

> [...] Before you can do any assertions you’ll need to dispatch a request. You can use one of the following methods to send a request:
>
> - get() Sends a GET request.
> - post() Sends a POST request.
> - put() Sends a PUT request.
> - delete() Sends a DELETE request.
> - patch() Sends a PATCH request.
> - options() Sends an OPTIONS request.
> - head() Sends a HEAD request.

So something like this:

```php
$this->get('/pages/index');
```

And after that you can use assertions accordingly.

See **[Cookbook > Testing > Controller Integration Testing](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#controller-integration-testing)**

Comment: yeah this works. thank you. can you tell me how i can assertlayout empty ?
i have this in the controller $this->viewBuilder()->setLayout(false);
but i cannot run this $this->assertLayout(""); because i become this error Failed asserting that '' equals layout file .

Comment: @Pla558 `assertLayout()` seems to only works with an actual layout name present. Maybe that could be considered a bug, or maybe just a limitation, not sure, you may want to open an issue over [**at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues). You can always test the `_layoutName` property yourself, like `$this->assertNull($this->_layoutName)`.